# ASP MVC/EF 4 Design - to use a viewmodel or not?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, viewmodel

I have a list of somewhat complex entity graphs representing video game reviews.  I'm going to create separate navigation based on the graphs' properties - game title, platform name(s), genre.  At the end, it will be Wiki-like.

What I'm wondering is this - should I do the work to grab this navigation info in my controller and store it all in a view model, or should I simply pass my list of graphs into the view, and manipulate it there?  Does it matter, in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT is good convention to use a ViewModel when passing information to the views. ViewModel suggests a link to a View. In a perfect world then we would use 1 ViewModel per View

there is a [great article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/) by Jimmy Bogard (author of MVC 3 in Action) that could help here